# How to connect to em console through wlst

Tags: weblogic, wlst, oracle-fusion-middleware

I trying to connect to em console through wlst. But I could connect only to weblogic admin console. I need to change some of the mediator properties(soa-infra which is a web application) through em console. Can anyone please help me in connecting to emconsole and thereby changing the mediator properties.
 For this I executed oracle_home/oracle_common/common/bin/wlst.sh

Answer (score 2):

Everything goes through the admin console, since that controls the entire domain and deployments/applications. The following links all have examples on how to edit soa-infra properties:

http://rreddy.blogspot.com/2012/03/wlst-soa-mbeans-examples.html

http://bibeksoa.blogspot.com/2013/10/wlst-script-soa-process-deployment.html

http://www.qualogy.com/wlst-change-script-to-soa-common-bpel-an-bpmn-properties/

http://go2kavinkumar.wordpress.com/2011/08/28/using-wlst-to-manage-web-service-policies/

Specifically you want to grab the `Application=soa-infra` object to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the EM console installed. It may not me installed in your domain by default (unless you checked it when creating your domain).

You can add the EM console by running config.sh from your domain and selecting Enterprise Manager console from the list. Then you should be able to access it via

```
http://admin_server_url:port/em
```